# Redux create reducer expected

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

Good morning,
while using redux I have the following error, I have configured the reducer and the actions what, what should I fix?

**Error: Expected the reducer to be a function.**

**Code:**

```
import {createStore} from "redux";

const initalUser={
    IdUtente: 0
 };

const store=createStore(
    initalUser
  )

function userset(state=initalUser,action,value){
    switch(action){
        case "Login":
           state=value;
           return state;
        default:
          return state;
    }
}
export function userReducer(idUtente){ 
    store.userset(initalUser,"Login",idUtente);
}
export function getUser(){
    return store.getState();
}
```

Comment: `initalUser ` is an object ... and it should be a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly, pretty much everything you do here is incorrect.
`createStore` needs to be called with the reducer, not the initial state. `userset`  does not magically become a property of the store, and you have written it more like a reducer than an action creator - but it is not a valid reducer (that would only accept two arguments) and you have no dispatched action anywhere to be seen in that code.

So, this would need to look like

```js
import {createStore} from "redux";

const initalUser={
    IdUtente: 0
 };

const store=createStore(
    userReducer
  )

function userReducer(state=initalUser,action){
    switch(action.type){
        case "Login":
           return action.payload;
        default:
          return state;
    }
}

export function userSet(idUtente){ 
    store.dispatch({ type: "Login", payload: idUtente });
}

export function getUser(){
    return store.getState();
}
```

and even that would not be very typical redux code.

Adding to all this: **This is a very outdated style of redux that we are not recommending to teach or learn any more**.

Please, ignore whatever tutorial you are following right now, go to the official redux tutorials at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/index and follow both of them, from beginning to end (they start with old-style redux to explain the basics and then teach you modern redux, which looks very different).

Comment: i am a beginner with redux i have followed a series of tutorials on the net, thanks for the advice

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately there are a lot very outdated tutorials - that's why I'm linking the official ones - they are up-to-date and pretty good :)

Comment: do you know by chance there are also new video tutorials?

Comment: No, but if you are trying to watch any video tutorial, make sure that it is a video tutorial about "redux toolkit", not just "redux".